# Did I drill through a corner bead?

Tags: drywall, anchor, corner-bead

[image]I was drilling into the wall by a corner to hang a plant and went through a thin metal panel. My first thought was that it was protecting a stud but I only see what looks like insulation behind it.

My next thought was that this was a corner bead - you can see on the wall itself a thin line all the way down the wall.

Does anyone have any idea what I drilled through? :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Give us another picture with some context - how far from the corner is this?

Comment: How far from the corner is the hole? You might be trying to anchor into nothing...

Comment: Added a couple more pictures; it’s about 3/4” away from the corner.

Comment: Any chance this place is built with metal studs?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you drilled through corner bead.

If the object is really light, go for it, but you're basically putting a fastener between the back of the drywall and a stud, so it really isn't strong. 1.5-2" from the corner gets you reliably into the stud.